# Submitting form data with php with no page reload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, curl

I have a contact form, on my personal portfolio webpage, made with PHP with a friends help (i'm a dummy when it comes to PHP.)

Although i have a problem with it. Whenever the submit button is pressed, and the mail is sent, it makes the page reload. How can i fix this?

I've copied (and changed the personal stuff) all my form, since i have no idea where or what to change:

```html
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $commentErr = $subject = "";
    $name = $email = $comment = $subject = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $name = input($_POST["name"]);
      }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
              if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid e-mail format"; }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subjectErr = "Subject is required";
      } else {
        $subject = input($_POST["subject"]);
      }

      if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
        $commentErr = "Comment is required";
      } else {
        $comment = input($_POST["comment"]);
      }
}

// MailGun cURL API //
  $curl_post_data=array(
    'from'    => "$name <$email>",
    'to'      => 'my@mail.com',
    'subject' => $subject,
    'text'    => $comment,
);

  $service_url = 'mailgunlink.com';
  $curl = curl_init($service_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:key-123456789123456789abc");

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
  $response = json_decode($curl_response);
  curl_close($curl);



// trim //
    function input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }

?>

    <section id="kontaktformular">
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
  <div class="row" id="kontakt">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label>Full Name <span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span></label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Peter" name="name" id="navn">

    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <label>Your Email <span class="error">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></span></label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Peter@Example.com" name="email" id="email">

    </div>

    <label>Subject <span class="error">*<?php echo $subjectErr;?></span></label>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Design" name="subject" id="subject">

    <label>Message <span class="error">*<?php echo $commentErr;?></span></label>
    <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Whatever..." name="comment" id="besked"></textarea>

    </label>
    <input class="button-primary change" type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
</form>
    </section>
```

I hope the snippet is sufficient, even though it looks messy like this. 
If you need more information feel free to yell at me for it.

Also, bonus question. I need the submit button to also HIDE the form (display: none; -> #kontaktformular) and SHOW another div (display: block; -> #feedbackmsg)

Thanks in advance! The first question is the most important!

Comment: _AJAX?_ thats the way to go!

Comment: Ever tried Ajax?

Comment: Thanks guys, i've been looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, but again - im really a dummy at PHP and only a beginner at jQuery. Thanks though.

Comment: (sorry for bad english) you need to read ajax tutorials first...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this question has already been asked and answered multiples. Either way to do it you'll have to use AJAX which is pretty simple and one way to do it is.

```
<section id="kontaktformular">
  <form id="kontaktform" method="post">
    <div class="row" id="kontakt">
      <div class="six columns">
        <label>Full Name <span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Peter" name="name" id="navn">

      </div>
      <div class="six columns">
        <label>Your Email <span class="error">*</span></label>
      </div>
      <label>Subject <span class="error">*</span></label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Design" name="subject" id="subject">
      <label>Message <span class="error">*</span></label>
      <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Whatever..." name="comment" id="besked"></textarea>

      </label>
      <input id="kontaktform_input" class="button-primary change" type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#kontaktform").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
         success: function(data)
         {
         }
       });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm this did not work. I'm testing this on localhost - does that matter?

Comment: I have jQuery yeah, although it's another version.
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It seems like you are right. Thank you so much sir! 
Can you explain why using and older jQuery version? Should'nt i be using 1.7.1?

Comment: Well - work and work. Now the submit button doesnt reload the page, however the checking for email format and whether all fields are filled doesnt work, together with the fact that the mail doesnt get send?

Answer (score 2):

Yes AJAX is the answer you are looking for in this case:

Add an ID to the submit button eg.

> ```
>     <input class="button-primary change" id="Kontakt_Submit" type="submit" value="Send">
> ```

Then next in your js file write a similar code

```
    jQuery("#Kontakt_Submit").click(function () {
      //serialize the data, in simple terms for you to understand, it will
      // get all the input element name value, then this data will be sent as POST DATA
      var data = jQuery('form').serialize();
      console.log('data-->' + data);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {
            check: 'Kontakt_Form',
            Kontakt_Form_Data: data
        },
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
});
```

Next in your ajax.php file add this code

```
    if ($_POST['check'] == 'Kontakt_Form') {
         $result_array = array();
         $extracted_Array= array();                          // since we declared          both the variable names as "value" in JQuery
         parse_str($_POST['Kontakt_Form_Data'], $extracted_Array);
         $name= $extracted_Array['name'];
         $email= $extracted_Array['email'];
...//do the the other things what you need to do here, then enter in result array and return it for your output values if any.
}
```

Hope this will help you understand in a simple way to set up what you wanted.

Comment: Ugh i dont know if it is because this is late or what, but im lost right now. 
But you talk about "my" ajax.php and js file. All my form is written in the .html file. 

The js i'm fine with, but i honestly dont know what to do with the ajax.php? And "...//do the the other things what you need to do here, then enter in result array and return it for your output values if any." ?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience - i appreciate the help! I just understand nothing of php.

Comment: So could you help me how to implement this? 
I know i've already marked the other answer as right, but it created new problems - so i ditched it again